# Javascript to change the text color

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table that displays the value like below:

```
<table id="tableID">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Column heading 1</th>
  <th>Column heading 2</th>
  <th>Column heading 3</th>
  <th>Column heading 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td> ID (43.1)</td>
  <td>Class (-23)</td>
  <td>Age (89.6)</td>
  <td>Num (-5)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ID (-4)</td>
  <td>Class (-3)</td>
  <td>Age (0)</td>
  <td>Num (98)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ID (10)</td>
  <td>Class (-32)</td>
  <td>Age (7)</td>
  <td>Num (2)</td>
</tr>
```

The task at hand is that I like to change the text color on condition basis. IF the value is negative, it should be displayed in Red, else Green. 
I have no idea how to change this, till now I'm able to create the below javascript code, but not sure how to handle the text color and which event should I use. Can someone please provide directions.

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID'),
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
cells[i].onready = function(){ // onready .. will that work??
    console.log(this.innerHTML);

}
}
```

EDIT: this is how I'm generating HTML table

```
function generateTable($associative_array){
echo '<table width="620" id ="optimization" class="optimization_table"><thead><tr><th>';
echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($associative_array)));
echo '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach ($associative_array as $row){
    array_map('htmlentities', $row);
    echo '<tr valign="middle"><td>';
    echo implode('</td><td>', $row); 
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be done on server, when generating HTML

Comment: can you provide a sample code how to tweak the code. may I'll build on it

Comment: And what does `$row` really look like here? It would be easier to grok if you add regular iteration to create the cells, rather than imploding the rows with tags to create four cells

Answer (score 2):

Get the cells, iterate over them, get the numbers, compare agains zero to see if negative/positive, set color, done ...

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID td');

for ( var i=0; i<cells.length; i++ ) {
    var cell    = cells[i];
    var html    = cell.innerHTML;
    var changed = html.replace(/([+-]?(\d|\.)+)/, function(x) {
        var color = (+x) < 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
        return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + x + '</span>';
    });

    cell.innerHTML = changed;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/watgabt8/3/)

Comment: A suggestion: Use `/([+-]?\d+)/` instead of matching anything that is inside parenthesis. More flexible.

Comment: @Tushar - Sure, matching just the hyphen and numbers is probably better

Comment: unfortunately, it is changing the entire color of the table and making it green

Comment: @user4943236 Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: yeah, the fiddle looks good, but on implementing this.it changes the color .. and one more thing, I just need to change the color of the text inside brackets to be changed.. not the entire text in the coloum

Comment: Then tag the question with PHP, and post readable PHP code where it's possible to wrap the parts in the parentheses in spans etc. In fact, maybe you should post a new question on how to do this entirely in PHP.

Comment: If the entire table changes color, you either didn't copy the code above correctly, or you have invalid HTML. You did close the tbody and table ?

Comment: Also updated the answer to only change the color *inside* the parentheses.

Comment: I tried running your code, actually the text before parenthesis getting colored for the first cell.. all remaining cells are in black font only

Comment: @adeneo, I debugged the code,and when I run {var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#optim');} this line, it gives me an array of 2 tables. will the code expect to run then as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99887/discussion-between-user4943236-and-adeneo).

Comment: And that's not what I posted, is it. You're getting the table, not the cells, look at the code above again.

Comment: @adeneo, possible to discuss it on chat pls.

Answer (score 0):

I share the same opinion as Tushar. If this table is dynamically generated, adding a class to the `<td>` based on the value is very easy. If not the table is manually generated, the same can be applied.

If you still want to accomplish this with Javascript (which I do not approve) you might want to ensure the numeric value is inside a `<td>` alone so that you can check its value and assign a class to its parent.

The class can be pre-defined in your styles to provide different colors..

Comment: thank you for your comment. I edited my comment, may I know how to tweak the dynamically generated table.. I'm noob in HTML and CSS. can you show me the way pls

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to process it back-end and you are confident that the character negative(-) will only be used for the numbers, you can try this

```
  var table = document.getElementById('tableID'),
  cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

  for (var i = cells.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    if( cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf('-') !== -1 )
      cells[i].style.color = 'red';
    else
      cells[i].style.color = 'green';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("table td");
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
  var num = parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]);
  if (num < 0) {
    cells[i].style.background = "red";
  } else {
    cells[i].style.background = "lightgreen";
  }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kof5ey41/)

Also note that you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to find the elements directly.